# Make Material-UI Dialog transition from another component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I have an image that when clicked opens a material dialog, I'd like the dialog to originate from wherever the image is.

I'm trying to do something with a transform origin and grow transition, but I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction:

```
class ImagePopup extends Component<Props>{
    popupTransition(props) {
        return <Grow
            {...props}
            style={{ transformOrigin: '1000px -500px 0' }}
            {...(true ? { timeout: 500 } : {})} />;
    }

    render() {
        return <Dialog TransitionComponent={this.popupTransition} onClose={this.props.close} open={this.props.previewImage}> <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                    Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
                    Google, even when no apps are running.
            </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    }
}
```

I think the only trick left is to figure out the transformOrigin of the image in screen space and set that in the popupTransition.

Besides that I would like to have it transition from the original size of the image component to a larger popup but I'm not sure if that's possible with the current way the dialog works.

How would I go about doing that or is there a better way of doing this?